# toggle highlight tr/td on live click, but don't toggle if clicking on input/select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can assist me, I think that it must be straight forward but I think I'm missing something... I've made a table that will highlight onclick or de-highlight if the same cell is clicked. This I don't have a problem with. What I'm having a problem with is that it still toggles if I click on an input:text or select element within the cell.

Is there a simple way of adding a not clause in the selectors, or by seeing if select/input was clicked on within the below?

```
$("#grid td, #grid th").live('click', function(){
    ...
    toggle highlight, image changes, link changes, etc,  when conditions are met (currently works)
    ...
});
```

I thought maybe could use the `.not()` function, but I think that it may not toggle if I still click in the cell, but not clicking on input/select.

Any help or assistance would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whats happening here is the event is bubbled up from the child elements to the parent cell.

You can do two things, one is to check which element triggered the event and only allowing it if its a td.. something like this:

```
$("#grid td, #grid th").live('click', function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td' || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'th') {
        //do your stuff here
    }

});
```

Or look at stopping the event on input and select click handlers with `cancelBubble` or `event.stopPropogation`

Comment: What if there is a span or some other element in td or th? Will `target.tagName` check work?

Comment: yup, the if is checking if the element triggering it is a td or th only

Comment: What am I doing wrong [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/cx58b/)? There is a `span` element in first `th` and when I click that `span`, `th` does not catch `click`

Comment: if you want the span to trigger the click as well then you need add it to the if: `|| e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#grid td input, #grid th input, #grid td select, #grid th select, #grid td textarea, #grid th textarea').live('click focus', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

EDİT: added `select` and `textarea`

Comment: added. Your solution is better than mine btw.

Comment: Because this is a `live` event, which bubbles all the way up before being handled, I don't believe that `stopPropagation` will do what you want.

Comment: You say so but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/BEA8S/1/) says different. So my answer is also a valid answer.